# Garbage collection implementation

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

In which language garbage collection algorithm is implemented  for java.i think c, please confirm?

Comment: Java is a language. The VM does garbage collection, but there are multiple implementations of the Java VM. You'll have to be more specific about which one you mean in order to get a good answer.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the JVM. Often, the garbage collector is implemented in the same language as the JVM, but that is not always the case.

In Maxine, both the JVM and the garbage collector are implemented in Java.

In Jikes, both the JVM and the garbage collector are implemented in Java.

In Rava, the JVM is implemented in Ruby and the garbage collector isn't implemented *at all*: Ruby already is a memory-managed language, there is no need to implement a separate garbage collector.

In IKVM, the JVM is implemented in C# and CIL and the garbage collector isn't implemented *at all*: the CLI VES already is a memory-managed environment, there is no need to implement a separate garbage collector.

In VisualAge for Java, the Java bytecode gets translated to Smalltalk bytecode and then executed by the Smalltalk environment. Smalltalk already is a memory-managed language, there is no need to implement a separate garbage collector.

In VMKit, both the VM and the garbage collector are written in C++.

In HotSpot, both the JVM and all 4 (or however many there currently are) garbage collectors are written in C++.

Answer (score 7):

The JVM can be implemented in any language, but Sun's HotSpot is written in C/C++ and assembly.

#### See also

- [Frequently Asked Questions about Garbage Collection in the HotspotTM JavaTM Virtual Machine](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/faq.html)
- [OpenJDK/The HotSpot Group](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/)

  > The HotSpot code base has been worked on by dozens of people, over the course of 10 years, so far. (That's good and bad.) It's big. There are nearly 1500 C/C++ header and source files, comprising almost 250,000 lines of code. In addition to the expected class loader, bytecode interpreter, and supporting runtime routines, you get two runtime compilers from bytecode to native instructions, 3 (or so) garbage collectors, and a set of high-performance runtime libraries for synchronization, etc.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK the Sun JVM is implemented mostly in C++ and assembler, so I'd guess that the GC is implemented in C++.

Answer (score 2):

As an example of my point that not all Java VMs are implemented in C++, consider [Jikes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jikes_RVM), which is meta-circular. It is completely implemented in Java. A minimal bootstrap section of the code is written in C, but the rest of the VM—including the memory management (MMTk)—is written entirely in Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the source code, download the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) source code. Warning: It is not going to be easy to understand, there are a number of very sophisticated garbage collection algorithms implemented in the JVM.